# Strange Oracle ORDER BY

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I have a problem sorting strings in french :

This is my query :

```
SELECT LIBELLE as LibelleCourant,
       CODE as code
FROM S_MARQST
ORDER BY LibelleCourant;
```

And this is the result

```
LIBELLECOURANT  | CODE
----------------------
BAYARD          | BAY
LESIER          | LES
<Non renseigné> | INC
PAM             | PAM
```

As you can see, oracle seem to ignore the `'<'` charactrer and order only with alphabet characters. `<Non renseigné>` is neither at the top nor at the bottom. I tried `NLSSORT(name, 'NLS_SORT=french');` but the result is the same.

I would like to have a basic ordering, with special chars either at the top or at the bottom (or both if it uses char codes, nevermind). As the data is user-generated, i cannot predict which chars will be used so i think i can not use CASE statements.

Thank you.

PS: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Prod

Comment: and if you try nls_sort=BINARY?

Comment: Thanks, this is a good step. It seems i missed this in the docs. However, Special letters like É or À are now sent to the bottom too (big char code i guess). Hopefully there are not many words concerned in our application. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so with the help of Munchi and kevinsky i mixed up their advice to arrive to this :

```
SELECT LIBELLE as LibelleCourant,
       CODE as code
FROM S_MARQST
ORDER BY NLSSORT(translate(libelle,'ÉéÀàÇçÈèÙù','EeAaCcEeUu'), 'nls_sort=BINARY');
```

So the sort BINARY sends values starting with `<` to the top (i would rather the bottom but eh .. it's ok) but before, special letters are translated to normal letters in the order clause.

That's good with French but a little bookkeeping may be necessary for other languages with many more special letters.

Answer (score 2):

I use this solution but it is not an elegant solution. It converts all accented french characters to english equivalents and strips out odd characters.

order by translate(LibelleCourant,'ÉéÀàÇçÈèÙù''/*;"<>() ','EeAaCcEeUu')

Edit:  if you want to keep the special characters to sort by then change the translate function.
Example: you want to keep the < and > symbols, just add them to the end string
order by translate(LibelleCourant,'ÉéÀàÇçÈèÙù<>''/*;"() ','EeAaCcEeUu<>')

What is happening is that any single character which is present in the first string and has a corresponding value in the second string will be replaced.  Extra characters will be removed.  These characters will be replaced ÉéÀàÇçÈèÙù<>
and these characters will be removed:          ''/*;"()

See the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions196.htm) for more info.

Comment: Thank you, but with this,`<Non renseigné>` is  treated like `Nonreseigne` so it is not sent to the bottom but still mixed with the values starting with `N`.